# What does "to be like out" mean?

Tags: meaning

This is a sentence "**With their unrealistic view of this war, our generals don’t know
what things *are like out* in the trenches.**" from a TOEFL book.

I dont not undestant what sentence means because of "to be like out". I could not find on internet. I would like to know what it is grammatically or how to approach it.

Thanks.

Comment: It would just as well have been phrased as *our generals don’t know what **things out in the trenches** are like.* Then you wouldn't have mis-parsed it.

Answer (score 2):

You have parsed this incorrectly, "be like" is part of one phrase, and "out" heads the another "out in the trenches".

The generals don't know "what things are like"  (ie they *don't know the how thing are*)  in the location "out in the trenches". You can read this as "out there, in the trenches".

You can infer that the generals don't have experience of life on the front line in a war.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You enlightened me.